# find pom dependencies by classname

Tags: java, maven-2, dependencies, pom.xml

How can I found the dependency by classname?

In particular, I want to include this class org.mortbay.jetty.testing.ServletTester in my project, how do I do that? And how did you find the answer?

Comment: IDE stuff is cool, but I came across the situation it not works. It would be cool to have a _maven plugin_ for that. To search for class within project dependencies. Something to be used like `mvn search:class -Dclass=org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPTransportFactory`. Currently running my app with `mvn jetty:run` and don't see this class in IDEA however seeing it is loaded when running under debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since version 6.1, Netbeans can [add to pom.xml the dependency you need for a given class](http://wiki.netbeans.org/MavenBestPractices#section-MavenBestPractices-Hints)

Comment: good... **todo:** have a closer look at netbeans. however, I was looking for a more general answer.

Answer (score 11):

[Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/) allows you to search for artifacts by class name as well as GroupId, ArtifactId, and Version. Nexus uses Lucene to index artifacts. The [Sonatype public repository](http://repository.sonatype.org) allows you to search the major repositories.

Enter org.mortbay.jetty.testing.ServletTester in the search field and hit the search icon. You'll get no results because by default Nexus searches for keywords. To refine the search to match class names, select the down arrow next to the *Keyword Search* label on the search page and select *Classname search* (see screenshot). You'll then find a list of matching artifacts.

[image: search screenshot]
<sub>(source: [sonatype.com](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/figs/web/meta_search-selection.png))</sub>

Nexus also has [Opensearch](http://www.opensearch.org/Home) integration, so you can add the search to your Firefox / IE 7 search field. See the [Nexus book](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/search-components.html) for more details on setting this up.

There's also a [video](http://www.sonatype.com/products/nexus/features/search_repositories) with more details on the search options available.

Comment: is there any way to use this approach to search non-Nexus public repositories?

Comment: it works on any public repository that has a nexus index (most do). If you have your own Nexus server, you can set up a proxy repository for the public repo, then search that repo using its index

Comment: It would be cool to find a maven plugin that searches not abstract dependencies but dependencies of a given POM. Use case: in a project with lot of dependencies, find a dependency where a given class belongs to.

Answer (score -1):

Use http://www.jarvana.com/ or use Intellij IDEA

Comment: The site: http://phraa-lby.com/zclkvisitor/86e47861-5080-11ee-a53b-1297cf7bdc7f/72092e88-2c53-401c-b988-51ef43ce1034 is blocked because the web filter identified it as "Malicious Sources/Malnets"