# In Eclipse, how to search for a class in maven managed dependencies?

Tags: eclipse, class, maven, jar, dependencies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [find pom dependencies by classname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371986/find-pom-dependencies-by-classname)

When all my dependencies are managed by maven in eclipse, then how do I use something like Ctrl+ Shift+ T to search for a dependency?

Comment: Ctrl-Shift-T works for me, even for Maven-managed dependencies. It even pulls down the sources automatically. Are you sure they are on the classpath (in the Maven container)?

Comment: to use Ctrl+Shift+T for maven managed, make sure that the m2 repositories should be available in the project build path libraries.

Comment: Yes, M2_REPO is in classpath variables. I am able to add the jar files directly as Project->Maven->Add Dependacny. Only C+S+T is not working.

Comment: It would be cool to have a _maven plugin_ for that. Something to be used like `mvn search:class -Dclass=org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPTransportFactory`. Currently running my app with `mvn jetty:run` and don't see this class in IDEA however seeing it is loaded when running under debugger.

Answer (score 7):

I assume you are using m2e plugin (and using it correctly)

Ctrl-Shift-T works for classes in JARs under library of your Eclipse project.  By using M2E plugin, dependencies of Maven is showed as a library.

Please verify if you see "Maven Dependencies" as one of the libraries under your project.  If not, probably you are either incorrectly importing the project, or the POM is having problem.

Comment: I can see maven dependancies as library. Once I add a dependancy then I can search for it's classes using Ctrl+Shift+T.

However what I want is to know is what exact dependancy to include when I only know the class name.

Comment: @PrashantBhuruk, Well, Eclipse IDE will list Classes from the jar files which are added as dependency. If you only know the class name and would like to add that jar to the classpath then first you have to find the jar file probably using sites like www.jarfinder.com, then add its artifacts id in pom.xml.

Comment: I was wondering if Maven knows how to provide depedencies to my project then there must be some way to search for the class files that are bundled in those dependecies. 

However, I think i will need to search in .m2 folder given a class name and then add the dependancy in eclipse.

Comment: @Prashant I don't know how you come up with this conclusion.  Dependencies is just a way to tell Maven which JAR (or other kind of artifact) to look for, it has nothing to do with finding a dependency jar for you by giving a class name

Comment: Can we do it in repositories like nexus / artifactory? Somewhere it was mentioned that "find artifact by class" is available.

Comment: a search in google with "find maven artifact by class name"  give me this site:  http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/  and even this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371986/find-pom-dependencies-by-classname

Comment: Thanks @AdrianShum 
Now working on Nexus to manage my repositories, since it was mentioned that Nexus allows you to search for artifacts by class name as well as GroupId, ArtifactId, and Version. 

Searching for exact artifact on any jar finder utilities would also have worked. However I wanted a means to search 'in' those dependencies that my Maven as already downloaded or configured with. 

Giving Nexus a try.